# Check when package repo last updated

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, packaging

Is there a way to check *when* the current version of a package (that would have been installed when using **apt install**) was released, from within terminal? The intention is to check how out of date the package might be.

**apt show** only shows a version number. This is not what I want. Searching on the web continues to show me results along these lines

Once I open up the browser, I can get this info by looking at the changelog on the packages.ubuntu.com website, but not having to open up the browser each time I want to do this would be much nicer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download and read the changelogs of packages from the Ubuntu repositories from the command-line, using the `apt changelog` command.

Example: `apt changelog firefox`

```
firefox (63.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) xenial; urgency=medium

  * Update AppArmor profile as the shmem temp filename changed upstream (the
    profile needs to allow access to /{dev,run}/shm/org.mozilla.*)
    - update debian/usr.bin/firefox.apparmor.14.10
    - update debian/usr.bin/firefox.apparmor.13.10

 -- Chris Coulson <chris.coulson@canonical.com>  Tue, 23 Oct 2018 22:14:25 +0100

firefox (63.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) xenial; urgency=medium

  * New upstream stable release (63.0build2)

 -- Olivier Tilloy <olivier.tilloy@canonical.com>  Mon, 22 Oct 2018 15:51:23 +0200

firefox (63.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) xenial; urgency=medium

  * Do not require Node.js to build, as version 8.11 isn't available in xenial
    - update debian/config/mozconfig.in
    - update debian/control{,.in}

 -- Olivier Tilloy <olivier.tilloy@canonical.com>  Wed, 17 Oct 2018 21:59:49 +0200

[...]
```

Note however that not all repositories and packages necessarily provide changelogs, and not all changelogs need to contain useful information, depending on what you're looking for, but for the packages from Ubuntu's standard repositories, it should mostly be fine.